# Regex for getting exact git email configured

Tags: regex

Here is the `git show -s HEAD` output

```
smilyface@smilingface /d/workspace/shirt (develop)
$ git show -s HEAD
commit f601411d4be3c3fbafea79c72ecc84ad78219265
Author: Smily Face <v-smily@somedomaingoeshere.com>
Date:   Wed May 29 15:22:45 2019 +0530

    Ticket-249843 : [shirt team apps] Deprecation of x function in Jenkinsfile
```

**Here is what I have tried -**

**Try 1 :**

```
git show -s HEAD | grep "Author:" | grep -Po '(?<=(<)).*(?=@)'
```

**Output:**
v-smily

**Problem :** 
Sometimes the email could start `with v-` and sometimes `without v-`. 

For example - **Email and Output expected** 
abcd@somedomaingoeshere.com -> abcd
v-xyz@somedomaingoeshere.com -> xyz
v-pqr@somedomaingoeshere.com -> pqr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick with PCRE, you may use

```
git show -s HEAD | grep -oP 'Author:.*<(v-)?\K[^@]+'
```

The `Author:.*<(v-)?\K[^@]+` pattern matches `Author:`, any 0+ chars up to the rightmost `<` that is optionally followed with `v-`, then `\K` is used to delete all matched text from the match buffer, and then `[^@]+` matches 1+ chars other than `@`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TUhKdD/1) and the [online `grep` demo](https://ideone.com/EXQw1C).

Alternatively, use

```
git show -s HEAD | grep -oE 'Author:.*<[^@]+' | sed -E 's/Author:.*<(v-)?//'
```

Extract a string starting with `Author:`, any 0+ chars, `<` and then 1+ chars other than `@`, and then use `sed` to remove what you do not need, all the string from `Author:` up to `<` and an optional `v-`.